# Trigger JS in custom meta box if a featured image is loaded/exists

Tags: ajax, metabox, post-thumbnails, post-meta

Playing with WordPress customization I created a meta box with several others that report back details of the post.  One meta box evaluates the featured image but I am having trouble figuring out how to fire the AJAX in the content of the meta box.  At first I thought I would need to look into `admin-ajax.php` so I followed [Using AJAX With PHP on Your WordPress Site Without a Plugin](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress) but after looking into it I need to check if the post has a thumbnail loaded in the meta box content. I searched under the tag [media](/questions/tagged/media) and tag [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and what I found was [Trigger JS when featured image upload window is opened in admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202988/trigger-js-when-featured-image-upload-window-is-opened-in-admin) which led me to search for `wp.media.featuredImage` but how can I build my function with AJAX to run when the featured image is loaded but if it isn't then do not.

I can get it to work by using:

```
function foobar_metabox_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'metabox_meta_nonce' );
    $metabox_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <p>
        <!-- show results -->
    </p>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p>No Featured Image not loaded</p>
    <?php
    }

    // test the meta content
    $getPostCustom=get_post_custom();
    var_dump($getPostCustom);
}
```

but that is only if I refresh after the featured image has been loaded to the post.  How can I get the function `foobar_metabox_callback()` to run without refreshing using `admin-ajax.php` if possible?

Further reference:

- [Wordpress wp.media Featured Image ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085701/wordpress-wp-media-featured-image-id)
- [How to detect changes in wp_editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462407/how-to-detect-changes-in-wp-editor)

Comment: Why not look at the featured image metabox and when the image is added there then continue your actions? `$('#postimagediv .inside img')` ..

Comment: Eww..  that is an idea.  Didnt think about it that way.

Comment: I did notice wp adds two classes to the thumbnail.  It might work if i write a conditional for the class but ill still have to figure out how to work the AJAX.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain the AJAX part? Thank you.

Comment: Trying to think how to call the jquery once the thumb is loaded but will test.

Comment: Ah. I don't think there's an event to listen for to tell that the image has been added but you can set check for the image repeatedly on DOM ready: `window.setInterval(function () { /* check if image is there with $('#postimagediv .inside img') or so, if so then do things and stop this interval w/ clearInterval method */ }, 400);`

Comment: Why not make it an answer so i can rep you?  Add all what you have in the comment to explain so it makes since after i nuke my comments.

Comment: Thanks I have tried to compose an answer but not successful so here's a paste http://pastebin.com/tnF79dQ8

Comment: @SamuelElh what was your issue with posting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any WP specific event to hook in to. What you can do is set up an observer with a callback to respond to DOM changes using `MutationObserver` and check if the your featured image has been added in the callback.

There's [no support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) in IE < 11 though, which may be a deal breaker for you, or maybe not.

I've done minimal testing on this, but it works for me:

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {

    // Fires every time a mutation occurs...

    // forEach all mutations
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

        // Loop through added nodes
        for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; ++i) {

            // any images added?
            if ( mutation.addedNodes[i].getElementsByTagName('img').length > 0) {
                alert('Featured Image Added');

                // Your featured image now exists
                console.log( $('#postimagediv img') );

                // Do some AJAX...
            }
        }
    });
});

// define what element should be observed (#postimagediv is the container for the featured image)
// and what types of mutations trigger the callback
var $element = $('#postimagediv');
var config = { subtree: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

observer.observe( $element[0], config );
```

There's probably a better way to check for the featured image than just checking for an `img` element. You may want to have a var to keep track of the featured image so you can easily check for it being removed too (or just check `removedNodes` in the observer callback).

This won't run on page load so you should check if a featured image exists there first.

Further reading on the Mutation Observers:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers
- https://davidwalsh.name/mutationobserver-api
- http://ryanmorr.com/using-mutation-observers-to-watch-for-element-availability/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546242/1990216

Answer (score 2):

Very broad solution.

There are two problems you are facing

1. there are different HTML generated by the server based on if there is a featured image
2. Meta box are just a UI artifact of post editing and are not easily manipulated via AJAX (even in AJAX it is easier to handle full objects rather then their individual properties, even if only for keeping everything in sync)

The solution is by removing point 1 and keeping everything in the client. Add all the HTML as if there is a featured image, just hide it with `display:none` or similar.

Now all you have to do is to monitor when a feature image is inserted, probably via DOM mutation event or whatever you can do with jQuery (there might even be an event raised by WP JS that associates the image). Once you detect that the image is there you can update whatever values you have in the metabox and remove the `display:none`.

You are unlikely to get the same exact behavior as when the html is rendered with the featured image already there, depending on the complexity of what you do, but you should be able to get something that is good enough.